# Can I change datetime-local format for django-filters?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I'm using django-filters for a datetime filter.

When I try to use datetime-local my form sends the date time query like this:

2020-07-07T18:39

But my django-filter accept the format just like this:

2020-07-07 18:39

And here is my django function for django-filter:

```
def paketdok(request):
    siparis_list = Siparisler.objects.filter(paketlenme_tarihi__isnull=False)
    siparis_filter = PaketFilter(request.GET, queryset=siparis_list)
    return render(request, 'paketlenmis_arama.html', {'filter': siparis_filter})
```

My PaketFilter:

```
paketlenme_tarihi = django_filters.DateTimeFromToRangeFilter(widget=django_filters.widgets.RangeWidget(attrs={'type':'datetime-local'}))
```

Can I change the format of datetime-local input field somehow?

Comment: Please show the definition for `PaketFilter` too.

Comment: I've added that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change what `datetime-local` does - for sanity's sake, it will always output an ISO8601 datetime.

Happily, though, django-filter ships with [`IsoDateTimeFilter`](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/79b4ea7535b5d6760afad736361dff08bfd1fda9/django_filters/filters.py#L273) / [`IsoDateTimeField`](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/79b4ea7535b5d6760afad736361dff08bfd1fda9/django_filters/fields.py#L130), which accept ISO8601 datetimes.

You should be able to just switch to that filter or field.

Comment: When I change the filter to IsoDateTimeFilter get this error: AttributeError at /paketlenmisler/arama/
 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: If your original was a `DateTimeFromToRangeFilter`, you'll naturally need to use `IsoDateTimeFromToRangeFilter` :)

Comment: Checked the documentation and used IsoDateTimeFromToRangeFilter. And now it's working. Thanks